# How to configure remote upstream without `git push`

Tags: git, git-remote

Is it to possible to configure the remote upstream branch for a **new** local branch without doing a `git push`?

I thought this is what `--set-upstream-to` option of `git branch` is for but I get the following error:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to remote2/foobar foobar

fatal: the requested upstream branch 'remote2/foobar' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.setUpstreamFailure false"
```

I'm aware of the config for the push command to do this automatically when pushing but I do not want to use that. What I'm trying to do is writing a script that makes sure ‍main branch is pushed `remote1` while all other branches are pushed `remote2`. In particular I want it to (1) clone repo A from `origin1` (2) add `origin2` as a remote, (3) checkout a new local branch, (4) make sure `git push` on this branch goes to `origin1`. I thought I could do something like this but I get the error above:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:username/repo1.git $1
$ pushd $1
$ git remote add origin2 git@github.com:username/repo2.git
$ git checkout -b $1
$ git branch --set-upstream-to origin2/$1
$ popd
```

Comment: Where do you see that `git push` is called? git is just warning you that you can't set as upstream a branch that doesn't exist, which seems like the correct behaviour

Comment: What about `git branch --set-upstream-to origin2/$1 || git push -u origin2/$1` ? Or test that remote branch `origin2/$1` exists?…

Comment: do you want your script to simply set the upstream ? or does your script also run `git push` at some point ?

Comment: @LeGEC the former! I just want to set things up in a script so that when the user eventually calls `git push` things go to the correct remote.

Answer (score 2):

*If your intention is, in your script, to push to `origin2` :*

you can, especially in a script, explicitly type the full name of the remote reference, and additionally set the `-u` option to your `git push` command :

```
git push -u origin2 "$branch:refs/heads/$branch"
```

---

*If your intention is, in your script, to just set the upstream branch and not push :*

a "remote tracking branch" is just a setting (two actually) in your local `.git/config` file.

one hacky way to set a tracking branch that doesn't exist is to use `git config` :

```
git config "branch.$branch.remote" origin2
git config "branch.$branch.merge" "refs/heads/$branch"
```

Comment: > If your intention is, in your script, to just set the upstream branch and not push :

yes this is my intention.

I wonder if there's a non-hacky way.

Comment: The "non-hacky way" is to use `git branch --set-upstream-to` but that requires that the upstream exist, which requires that the branch exist in the remote (which you've forbidden here) *or* some *other* ugly hacks to fake that. Might as well stick with the hacky way, it's less hacky. 